# How to decode TripleDESCryptoService string in php?

Tags: php, vb.net, tripledes

the following code decrypts a string in VB:

```
Public Function Desencriptar(ByVal Input As String) As String

        Dim IV() As Byte = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("abcdefgh") 
        Dim EncryptionKey() As Byte = Convert.FromBase64String("hereGoesTheKey") 
        Dim buffer() As Byte = Convert.FromBase64String(Input)
        Dim des As TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider = New TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider
        des.Key = EncryptionKey
        des.IV = IV
        Return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(des.CreateDecryptor().TransformFinalBlock(buffer, 0, buffer.Length()))

    End Function
```

I would like to know how to duplicate this process into a php script for a mobile app service. Thanks.

Comment: PHP alone cannot but with "plugin" you may be able to, (search, install, update php.ini)

Comment: Are you using this encryption algorithm for compatibility with a legacy application? If not use `AesCryptoServiceProvider` as it uses `AES which is stronger than your current one...

Comment: Can you provide sample cipher text, key, and expected plaintext for testing?

Comment: @miken32 Of course, for example: karlo = A/o251XHauM=

Comment: That is plaintext and ciphertext; what is the key used for decryption?

Comment: For example: rpaSPvIvVLlrcmtzPU9/c67Gkj7yL1S5

Answer (score 2):

```
this code might help.
 <?php
    $key = "123456";
    function pkcs7_pad($text, $blocksize)
    {
        $pad = $blocksize - (strlen($text) % $blocksize);
        return $text . str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
    }

    $input = pkcs7_pad("test", 16);//16byte
   // $key = md5(utf8_encode($key), true);
    $td = mcrypt_module_open('tripledes', '', 'ecb', '');//ecb mode
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv (mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($td), MCRYPT_RAND);
    mcrypt_generic_init($td, $key, $iv);
    $encrypted_data = mcrypt_generic($td, $input);
    mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
    mcrypt_module_close($td);

    echo base64_encode($encrypted_data);
?>
```

and please look on this link for more detail [3DES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13402856/triple-des-encryption-on-c-sharp-and-php-yields-different-results)

Comment: this just dont work the same encrypt, decrypt as the vb class Im showing, and always returns different values